# Regular expression example: find table row based on matched table data

Tags: regex

I want to extract value of 3rd td where 1st td has value 'Total (A)+(B)+(C)'

```
                    <td class="tbmain" height="25"><b>Total (A)+(B)+(C)</b></td>

                    <td class="tbmain" align="right"><b>100,000</b></td>     

                    <td class="tbmain" align="right"><b>111,111,111</b></td>

                    <td class="tbmain" align="right"><b>101,101</b></td>

                </tr>
```

Comment: Please consider not to use regular exressions to parse HTML (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/577423)).

Comment: I'm using VBA to parse and HTML page that i'm receiving. Whats the best way then to parse if not regex? I can't uniquely identify the field via id either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with jQuery:

```
alert($("table tr td:contains('Total (A)+(B)+(C)')").siblings("td:eq(1)").html());
```

will return `<b>111,111,111</b>` adn this is the value of the 3rd td where the 1st td has `Total (A)+(B)+(C)` in the value

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yLwnC/)

You can do this too  when you get the table as string ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/yLwnC/1/))

But if you relay want do do this with regex, this can help:

```
<tr>(\s+)?<td.*?>(.*?)?</td>(\s+)?<td.*?>.*?</td>(\s+)?<td.*?>(.*?)</td>
```